# How to wrap text in MUI MenuItem?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

So I have some text that I need to show in the popover. I have the following code that makes the text to appear in one line. I need to make the text wrapped to have them displayed in multiple lines for UI reason but so far my update has not been successful. Any idea?

```
<Popover
  anchorEl={target}
  open={open}
  anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'middle', vertical: 'bottom' }}
  targetOrigin={{ horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'bottom' }}
  onRequestClose={handleRequestClose}
  animation={PopoverAnimationVertical}
>
  <Menu autoWidth={true}>
    <MenuItem style={{ width: '200px', height: '200px' }}>
      <p style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
        'aslkjflajdsljflskdjflsdfjlsjdfjdfjlasjkfadlsf'
      </p>
    </MenuItem>
    //this does not work....
  </Menu>
</Popover>
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try resetting the `whiteSpace` style --

```
 <MenuItem style={{whiteSpace: 'normal'}}>  
   <p>This song is just six words long. This song is just six words long.  This song is just six words long.  This song is just six words long.</p> 
 </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the [`whiteSpace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property to `normal` in the `MenuList` component using [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) like below:

```
<Menu
  {...}
  MenuListProps={{
    sx: {
      width: 230,
      '& .MuiMenuItem-root': {
        whiteSpace: 'normal',
      },
    },
  }}
>
```

If you want every `MenuItem` in your app to wrap long text, you can also set it in `createTheme`:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiMenuItem: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          whiteSpace: 'normal',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]